Parallel processing lidar point clouds to find best fit plane
I want to calculate surface roughness of lidar point cloud . For that i need to find best fit plane of the neighbors for each point and calculate the distance from the plane to the point. This process is taking long period of time when the radius is increased. I tried to use concurrent futures but this made it more slow than the code without parallel processing.
import numpy as np
import laspy
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
from scipy.spatial import cKDTree as KDTree
from skspatial.objects import Plane

def process_point(point_idx, point, lidar_data, neighborhood_radius, tree):
    neighbor_indices = tree.query_ball_point(point, neighborhood_radius)
    neighbors = lidar_data[neighbor_indices]
    
    if neighbors.shape[0] >= 3:
        plane = Plane.best_fit(neighbors)
        # Distance calculation remains the same
        # Return roughness value and index
        return point_idx, calculate_distance_to_plane(point, plane)
    else:
        return point_idx, np.nan

# Parallel processing wrapper function
def calculate_roughness_parallel(lidar_data, neighborhood_radius, tree):
    roughness_values = np.zeros(len(lidar_data))
    with ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        futures = [executor.submit(process_point, point_idx, point, lidar_data, neighborhood_radius, tree)
                   for point_idx, point in enumerate(lidar_data)]
        for future in futures:
            point_idx, roughness = future.result()
            roughness_values[point_idx] = roughness
    return roughness_values


if __name__ == "__main__":
    las = laspy.read("las0.laz")
    in_point = np.vstack((las.x, las.y, las.z)).transpose()
    tree = KDTree(in_point)
    roughness_result = calculate_roughness_parallel(in_point, 1, tree)

Is there any other way to make this faster?

In Python using multiple process causes data to be copied using pickle which is generally slow. It only worth it when the transferred data is small compared to the computing process. Copying the whole tree over and over as well as other object for computing each point is certainly very expensive. Copying the tree only N times with N processes should be better though it may not be enough.

You can try to use threads instead to avoid this copy. However, this assume the target function release the CPython GIL (global interpreter lock). Otherwise, the GIL will prevent any performance improvement (it will actually be slower). Parallelism sucks in Python (especially CPython which is the standard implementation)...

An alternative solution is to rewrite the code using multiple threads in a native language like C/C++/Rust, or in Cython/Numba. This solution prevent you to use the current package in the computing part of the code you want to speed up and so it can make the code significantly more complex but significantly faster (especially since such solution is not limited by pickling nor the GIL nor even the interpreter). There is AFAIK no other (efficient) solution.

import numpy as np
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
from scipy.spatial import cKDTree as KDTree
from skspatial.objects import Plane

def process_batch(batch, lidar_data, neighborhood_radius, tree):
    results = []
    for point_idx, point in batch:
        neighbor_indices = tree.query_ball_point(point, neighborhood_radius)
        neighbors = lidar_data[neighbor_indices]

        if neighbors.shape[0] >= 3:
            plane = Plane.best_fit(neighbors)
            distance = calculate_distance_to_plane(point, plane)
            results.append((point_idx, distance))
        else:
            results.append((point_idx, np.nan))
    return results

def calculate_roughness_parallel(lidar_data, neighborhood_radius, tree, batch_size=100):
    roughness_values = np.zeros(len(lidar_data))
    batches = [(lidar_data[i:i + batch_size], neighborhood_radius, tree) 
               for i in range(0, len(lidar_data), batch_size)]
    
    with ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        futures = [executor.submit(process_batch, [(idx, point) for idx, point in enumerate(batch)], 
                                   lidar_data, neighborhood_radius, tree) 
                   for batch in batches]
                   
        for future in futures:
            for point_idx, roughness in future.result():
                roughness_values[point_idx] = roughness
    
    return roughness_values

if __name__ == "__main__":
    las = laspy.read("path/to/your/lasfile.las")
    lidar_data = np.vstack((las.x, las.y, las.z)).transpose()
    tree = KDTree(lidar_data)
    roughness_result = calculate_roughness_parallel(lidar_data, 1, tree)


The process_batch function now takes a batch of points and returns a
list of results. Each element in the list corresponds to a tuple
containing the point index and the calculated roughness (or np.nan if
the conditions aren't met).
The main function now divides the input data into batches and submits
each batch as a separate task to the executor. This significantly
reduces the overhead associated with task submission and management.
I've used a placeholder function calculate_distance_to_plane,
assuming you have this function defined elsewhere.
The optimal batch size (batch_size=100) is something you would need
to experiment with.


Welcome to stack-overflow. You should explain your solution and not just post a code like this (though my above comment give some hints). I advise you to read how-to-answer.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
